# Managing Kindle Collections from a computer

Tags: kindle, software, cataloguing, collections

I have plenty of e-books on my Kindle (some in the cloud and some in local only) and I created many Collections to classify my books.

One silly things I tried first time was to create a folder hierarchy in my computer and when I transfer the root folder in the Kindle, it was flatten; In fact I learn after the Collections are not equivalent to Folders (it would be too simple...).

After transferring few hundreds of books (and took some free ones from Amazon site) I did not found any other way to choose a Collection and then browsing all e-book from the kindle.

My question is: is there a way to prepare the Collections structure from the computer (Windows and Mac OS X) and to have the books already classified after transfer?

Comment: KDeasy only works if you have a Kindle device and not the Kindle App running on your PC, Phone, Ipad and other tablet.

Answer (score 7):

Some options are:

- There is [Kindle Collection Manager](http://www.kindlecollectionmanager.com/) (I didn't try that.) [Here are some instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/169088/how-to-effortlessly-manage-your-kindle-collections/). And [here you can find the developer](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=186305).
- Calibre also has a Kindle Collection manager plugin, here is a [howto](http://dearauthor.com/ebooks/using-kindle-collections-plugin-for-calibre/), a [semi-official forum](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118635).

Comment: The Kindle Collection Manager seems not able to retrieve the existing collections already in the Kindle. I have the last Paperwhite, then perhaps the sofware is not up-to-date. I will try with Calibre plugin soon and let you know.

Comment: @ruffp, even without the plug in Calibre, you can add tags to your books in Calibre and browse them that way.  For instance I put 'unread' tag on books as I import them, then when am I looking for what to read next I have a handy list of unread books.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Ok but are the tags considered as Collection on the Kindle side? Because my goals is to classify them on the Computer and then to be able to browse according to the classification on the Kindle itself.

Comment: Kindle Collection Manager is early beta and it is HIGHLY UNSTABLE. It ruined all my Kindle books. Make a full backup before you use it!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can have a good look at this free tool:

**[KDeasy Kindle Manager Freeware](http://www.kdeasy.com/)**.

It's available on Win and Mac, no need to jailbreak your Kindle devices.

[image: KDeasy Kindle Collections Manager]

Comment: Looks nice. I will try it and i'll accept your answer if i like it. The other ones looks a bit like not finished and old.

Comment: NO SUPPORT for collections if Kindle version is 5.6 or higher!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many programs but all of them are still in the experimental stage.
Note that at this moment (Oct 2015) **NO PROGRAM has support for Kindle v5.6 +**. I contacted developers of KDEasy and they quickly answered:

> So far we don't see any possibility to support 5.6, Amazon blocked all
>   the solutions. Sorry for that. Regards, KDeasy Product Manager Bansha

So, a big f*** you Amazon and thank you for locking this possibility while you provide such a cumbersome GUI interface.

Here is a resource that may help you if you have a version below v5.6. It is quite well documented:
http://www.epubor.com/4-ways-to-create-and-manage-kindle-collections.html

> Kindlian is a cool add-on for Kindle device and works on Windows
>   XP/Vista 7/8. It supports Kindle Keyboard&Kindle Black&Kindle Grey,
>   Kindle Touch, Kindle Paperwhite. The main function of this program
>   allows us to import and manage Kindle Books and collections.
>
> First Download and install Kindlian for win. Plug your kindle into a
>   computer and run this program.
>
> Step1: Choose your kindle version. (the follow step will take kindle
>   paperwhite as example.) Once you tap kindle paperwhite and press the
>   icon, the pop up screen prompts you to disconnect kindle.
>
> Tap "Settings" from kindle menu-->"Upadate your kindle". Then
>   reconnect kindle with your computer. At last press "OK". Then it will
>   enter the scan mode and then the new interface appears.
>
> Step 2: Create new collection. Click "+" and name your collection by
>   eBook author name, date, etc. Drag the books into the collection
>   folder which you create. And you can add epub books from your computer
>   to kindle device by clicking "Add files to Kindle" icon. Because it
>   will automatically convert epub books to mobi. But it will load DRM
>   epub books in failure. Download DRMed epub to mobi converter
>   alternative can help us make it. Download DRMed epub to mobi converter
>   alternative Windows Version Download Mac Version Download
>
> Once you finish adding books to your destination collection, and click
>   "disconnect" icon. Then it will prompt you to disconnect your kindle
>   with computer.
>
> When you disconnect your kindle with computer, tap
>   "Settings"-->"Update Your Kindle". At last, tap
>   "Settings"-->"Restart". Just for a while, the "kindle collection
>   test'' which I just create appears in my kindle paperwhite now.
>   Wonderful, I succeed in managing my kindle books.
>
> Note: The Kindlian just offer Window version. As a mac user, Scida
>   offer us a way to organize eBooks and manage our kindle device. The
>   method 3 also works with non Amazon books