# collection shows as empty and refuses to populate -- not syncing properly

Tags: kindle, amazon, sync, kindle-cloud-reader, collections

I had a few [collections](https://www.epubor.com/4-ways-to-create-and-manage-kindle-collections.html) on the Amazon Kindle web interface [populated](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/952/9853) with books purchased through Amazon, readable through the web reader.  However, I wasn't able get my Kindle to sync with the cloud so that they even showed as available until resetting the Kindle to factory defaults.

Might this be related to [pending deliveries](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122397/24327)?  Or, the [download queue](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/8030/9853)?

I confirmed that books were being downloaded, that there was sufficient free space.  And, yet, the Kindle showed the collections as empty *until* it was reset to factory defaults.

I even selected the items and attempted to [deliver](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122397/how-to-delete-or-manage-pending-kindle-deliveries) them to the specific device, which was reported as being successful.  However, the pending deliveries remained unchanged.

It was as if the items weren't showing due to incompatibility with the Kindle reader -- and yet, clearly, they were compatible.  How do I know that the items are compatible?  Because, by resetting the Kindle to factory defaults the content loads.  But, and here's the key point:  ***only after resetting the Kindle.***

Therefore, the problem lies with the Kindle itself, or at least how it syncs -- and not with the content.  Yet, it *seems* like the content is incompatible.

see also:

[Kindle collections and books not synching properly](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7296/9853)

That salient point being that other users report that what shows on `Manage Your Content`, the web interface, does not get similarly reflected on a Kindle e-book device.  What I describe is a little different, but, probably, the result of the same underlying bug.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are any purchased ebooks missing? Are you missing personal titles that you didn't buy but uploaded? If you are uploading your own titles, are these files a format that the Kindle reading system can understand?

Comment: Also, are you viewing in the web browser? If you are viewing it on a computer, wouldn't it be better to download the desktop app instead of using a web browser?

Comment: Not sure how else to state, or clarify.  Collections and books on Manage Your Content refuse to download to the Kindle **unless** or **until** the Kindle gets reset to factory defaults.   Obviously the content itself is compatible with the Kindle, since it eventually downloads and displays.  Manage Your Content meaning, to me, a website.  Kindle meaning a Kindle device with e-ink (not a fire tablet).

Comment: I have the same problem. I created all my collections in Kindle on my tablet. After a kindle update, it removed all my collections, now only 5 of 50 collections show up and the rest of my library shows as "Uncollected" meaning the book is no in a collection. On the amazon website under content, it shows all my books are in collections. This sucks when you have over 2000 books.

Comment: Strange that Kindle for PC is a 12 year old app and it still doesn't sync collections. With the rise of Kindle integrated apps like Readwise and personal learning platforms like Roam Research, Kindle for PC is becoming a more important and popular reader. Would be great to add cross platform collections syncing for Kindle PC.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see the problem (or one problem at least).

I have a massive set of collections on the kindle app for android. (Like 50 collections holding 2000 or more ebooks).

But when I install the Kindle for PC app for my Windows desktop, it does not let me import the organized collections from the Kindle app for android. When I use the Kindle for PC app, there is an IMPORT COLLECTIONS option, but it prompts me to choose between two older devices instead of my current android devices. These older devices used a type of collections which is different from the current one.

If I create a NEW collection on Kindle for PC and add ebooks to it, this new collection does not appear on my android app or even on Manage Your Content and Devices page.

You would assume that collections propagate to all Kindle platforms, but what I'm seeing now is that any collections you create on Kindle for PC will not be propagated onto your other reading systems. As you see, you can still access your ebooks, but you can't use the collections from your other devices.

You're not doing it wrong; the Windows program is just using an incompatible kind of collection system.

On the plus side, any collections you make on Kindle for PC are just for that computer -- and nothing else. (Just to be safe, I would create only a small number of collections on Kindle for PC). I have verified that annotations on the Kindle for PC propagate (albeit slowly) to other devices.

Comment: collections created on a Kindle won't show in Manage Your Content and Devices **unless** it's marked with a star to denote "downloaded".  Otherwise, I think it's just a bug.

Comment: I don't think that's true. On the kindle app for android, I create collections all the time and I see them in Manage your Content (95% of the time). The collections created on older e-ink devices don't show up in Manage Your Content -- I know that is true, but I thought on newer devices these collections will propagate.

Comment: FYI, I create collections on Manage Your Content and add ebooks to them -- then I'll see it on my kindle app. It's a two way street.

Comment: I'm not always seeing that, @idiotprogrammer -- the collection might show as empty.  **After** resetting the Kindle *then* the collection populates.